# How do you dynamically bind route-href parameters in Aurelia?

Tags: parameters, binding, routes, aurelia, router

I'm using pushState, and **not** using hashes for the URL structure.

I have a route, and it has a few parameter bindings - some optional:

```
route: [                        
     'chart/:chartType/:id',
     'chart/:chartType/:id/:view?',
     'chart/:chartType/:id/page/:page?',
     'chart/:chartType/:id/:view?/page/:page?'
],
```

and then I've got my route-href, and I have the necessary bindings on there:

`route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: { id: chartId, chartType: type, view: viewType, page: pageNum }"`

...but what if I don't ALWAYS want all route parameters for a `route-href`? As in, I'd like to be able to link to just a route that uses chartType and id without having to create separate routes for every single parameter combination I have on this route.

I know I can use "?" in the router config to designate a route optional, but how do I make the parameters optional in my route-href links?

Doing something like this throws an error:

`route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: { id: chartId, chartType: type, view?: viewType, page?: pageNum }"`

and I can't seem to use `.bind` syntax, like this (which also errors):

`route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: { id: chartId, chartType: type, view.bind: hasViewParam, page.bind: hasPageParam }"`

What's the magic syntax trick here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a `chartParams` property. Update this property whenever you change `chart`. Then, you can do this `route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: chartParams`. (I haven't tested this approach but I think it's gonna work)

Another option is generating the route manually. For example:

```
this.myRoute = this.router.generate(routeName, params);
```

Then, you can bind it to the link tag:

```
<a href.bind="myRoute">My Route</a>
```

Comment: Which answer doesn't work? The first or the second? There are 2 separated answers

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that while Aurelia can observe primitives, objects and arrays, it can't observe properties of objects or elements of arrays.

```
<a route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: { id: chartId, chartType: type, view: viewType, page: pageNum }">link</a>
```

This will work but will not update when `chartId`, `type`, `viewType`, and `pageNum` are updated. The value passed to the binding was the { id, chartType view, page } object, and Aurelia can't observe the properties of this object. Therefore, the best thing to do is to generate an object.

Perhaps in your view model you have:

```
export class ViewModel {
  chartId;
  type;
  viewType;
  pageNum;
}
```

Enhance it to this:

```
import { observable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ViewModel {

  @observable({ changeHandler: 'generateLinkParams'}) chartId;
  @observable({ changeHandler: 'generateLinkParams'}) type;
  @observable({ changeHandler: 'generateLinkParams'}) viewType;
  @observable({ changeHandler: 'generateLinkParams'}) pageNum;
  linkParams;

  generateLinkParams() {
    const { chartId, type, viewType, pageNum } = this;
    this.linkParams = { chartId, type, viewType, pageNum };
  }
}
```

Now, since the value of the linkParams object is being updated, and not just its properties, Aurelia will observe it. This results in the solution Fabio gave:

```
<a route-href="route.bind: chart; params.bind: linkParams">link</a>
```